# How to get max object in a list and replace it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am working on a genetic algorithm, defined a class:

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, N=1, K=1):
        self.wi = {}
        self.loss = 0
        id = random.sample([i for i in range(N)], K)
        wi = [random.random() for _ in range(K)]
        for i in range(K):
            self.wi[id[i]] = wi[i]
```

Generated a list of obj

```
population = [Solution(N, K) for _ in range(100)]
```

In my algorithm a new obj `C` will be created from the `population` list, and replace the obj in the `population` with the largest `loss`

I tried

```
largest = max(population, key = attrgetter('loss'))
largest = C
```

But the obj in the list do not change with `largest`, what can I do to make that happen?

Comment: You expected `largest = C` to alter the *list*? You need to find the *index*, and replace on that basis - `population[index_of_largest] = C`.

Comment: Rather than keep finding the `max()` object, why not keep these objects in a sorted list, or better still, a [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) as a priority queue? With [`heapq.heappoppush()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappushpop) taking an extreme element from the list while adding another is trivial and efficient; for `heapq` you only have to invert the `loss` value.

Comment: Simple enough, thank you @jonrsharpe

Comment: Great idea, Thanks a lot @Martijn Pieters♦

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calculating the maximum object, you can calculate the maximum index, and then set population for that index:

```
largest_i = max(range(len(population)),key=lambda i:population[i].loss)
```

and then set:

```
population[largest_i] = C
```

this will only scan the list once.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
from operator import attrgetter

largest = max(population, key = attrgetter('loss'))
largest = C
```

with

```
largest = max(population, key = attrgetter('loss'))
population[population.index(largest)] = C
```

Comment: This requires scanning `population` *twice*; once to find the largest, once to find its index. That is inefficient on larger populations.

Comment: Does the `index` method compare two object by all attributes? What about keys and values for attribute of `dict` type like `Solution.wi`?

Comment: compare address not value

Comment: @QuentinLewes as you haven't implemented `__eq__`, it will only match on object identity